EF Core does not show value from database trigger on adding entity
I have implemented a database trigger to populate a column in a specific table with a calculated value.
When DbContext adds a new instance of the entity and then saves it, the new instance does not include the automatically created value for the column. The database does show a correct value in the column for the newly inserted row.
When the data is retrieved in new call, the property is populate with the generated value.
Why would it not show correctly populated after adding even though the row in the database shows it's populated?

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes?tabs=v7#sqlserver-tables-with-triggers

@topsail thanks this is very good to know, we are actually currently still stuck on version 6.  Knowing about the change is good for our upgrade though!

If you have a calculated column, you can configure EF Core to always retrieve this column while preventing it from being used in INSERT and UPDATE operations:
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
    .Property(e => e.ProjectCode)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();


This worked as expected and was intuitive to implement.
